# AWS boto iterator returns bytes instead of strings: _csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, csv, boto

We have a large .csv file on an S3 bucket. We want to read it into a dictionary for processing line by line. botocore.response.StreamingBody provides an iterator that you can get with iter_lines(). However, it returns bytes, not strings, which is expected by the csv.DictReader. This throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "s3_iter_alternate.py", line 30, in process_file
    for row in csv_reader:
  File "C:\Users\Stan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\csv.py", line 111, in __next__
    row = next(self.reader)
_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)
```

What is the correct way to do this? I am a novice to Python. My code is below:

```
    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3', aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY,
                                 aws_secret_access_key = SECRET_KEY)
    s3_object = s3_resource.Object(bucket_name=BUCKET_NAME, key=OBJECT_KEY)

    resp = s3_object.get(Range=f'bytes={offset}-')
    body: botocore.response.StreamingBody = resp['Body']

    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(body.iter_lines(chunk_size=1024), fieldnames=FIELDNAMES)
    for row in csv_reader:
        print('Processing: ' + str(row)) #process here
    return
```

Comment: you need `encoding='UTF-8'` otherwise it will hand you bytes

Comment: @AnthonySottile how and where do I set this?

Comment: An alternative approach is to simply `download_file()` and then read the file locally, rather than loading the body into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Worked for me in Python 3 by wrapping `iter_lines` with `str`. Try this -

```
csv_reader = csv.DictReader(str(body.iter_lines(chunk_size=1024)), fieldnames=FIELDNAMES)
```

`iter_lines` returns bytes. Converting it to text string seems to do the trick.

Comment: I tried this, result was not quite what I expected. 
The resulting dictionary did not match the s3 file, and instead was mostly blank, other than first column, which had one character in each row, which, if read vertically spelled out:
"<generator object StreamingBody.iter_lines>". I am using Python 3.8.3. 

In the meantime I made this code work using a custom BodyLines class I found at https://medium.com/swlh/processing-large-s3-files-with-aws-lambda-2c5840ae5c91